Genexus 18 .net read exceldocument from blobfile
I need to read an Excel spreadsheet to input the data into another process. The Excel file is already in the database in blobfile format. When I try to open it, it appears blank. An example I tried:
&ExcelDocument.Open(ExcelBlobfile.FileURI)
It seems like I'm not reading the binaries correctly. Any suggestions?

You could try adding a variable &File data type File and do:
&File.Source = ExcelBlobfile.FileURI
&ExcelDocument.Open(&File.GetURI())


&File.Source = ExcelBlobfile
error spc0010: Type mismatch in assignment: &File.Source = ExcelBlobfile (Character=BinaryFile).

The difference is that ExcelBlobFile is Blob and not BlobFile, you could try &File.Source = ExcelBlobfile.FileURI
&ExcelDocument.Open(&File.GetURI())

I got it. I had inserted the attribute in blobfile format, changed it to blob, and your response worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

another method:
&blob = Blobfile //Attribute
&ExcelDocument.Open(&blob)
